# Looking for workaround for Firefox login autocomplete behaviour

Tags: firefox, html, autocomplete, ublock-origin, ublock

This question is related to the explanation on how Firefox handles autocompleting stored logins:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738090/why-firefox-autocomplete-even-with-different-input-name

I'm a regular user of a site that uses these three fields in its login form.

```
<input class="field" type="text" name="username" autocomplete="username" id="username">
<input class="field" type="text" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="emailRegister" disabled="disabled">
<input type="password" maxlength="1024" name="password" id="password">
```

Unfortunately Firefox always uses the field **right before** the password field as username field for autofill, so it fills the stored username into the hidden email input field.

Is there any way to workaround this so that username gets correctly filled in the username field, e.g. hiding the email field via a filter rule in ublock Origin?

Comment: You must have once entered the user-name into a field named `email`. I suggest to render the field visible (or create a trivial form with such a field), then delete the user-name from the list ([link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Deleting_autocomplete_entries)).

Comment: I already deleted and re-entered the login data (with username being in the username field), but as explained in the linked Stackoverflow question, Firefox *always* choses the field before to fill in the username data - in my case it's the email field.

Comment: If Firefox is really that stupid, then you have no choice but to change the order of the fields.

Comment: I'd do that, but it's a third party site. I wouldn't do s.th. odd like that for sure...

Comment: You could do that with a Greasemonkey userscript in Firefox. Takes some study.

Comment: Yeah, I reaiised that removing the element with uBlock Origin doesn't affect the internal autofill function of Firefox. The login form is on keepa.com BTW. I'm thinking about sending them a bug report, but I'm not sure if this is really a bug or actually intended to drive users to their browser extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is eleven years old in Firefox:
[Bug 499223 : Password manager fills logins into wrong / undesired fields](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=499223).
Three years ago was the last user complaint in that post, which was ignored and
never answered.

Therefore I suggest not to waste your time filing a new bug-report with Mozilla.

The above bug-report contains some workarounds, but they all are aimed at the
developer of the form, which is not your case.

All I can suggest is to use a Greasemonkey userscript to enable the `email` field,
so as to be able to manually correct the wrong value.
Alternatively, you could just force in the userscript the value of the field
to be your own email address, rather than the auto-filled one.